# Outdoor recording with TLM 103 microphones

Tags: field-recording, blimp, neumann, windscreens

Is there a way to mount two TLM 103 microphones into a blimp?

I'd like to have a compact stereo setup with those two mics, are there any options except two individual stands. I couldn't find something appropriate on the Rycote site, but maybe someone has other suggestions how to get them into a portable windscreen rig?

Comment: if there is no handheld solution, what would be a compact stand for this purpose? (ambience / field recording)

Answer (score 1):

TLM 103 are really of too large a form factor to be useful inside a blimp. You need there to be reasonable space between the inside of the blimp and the capsule. You should be looking at pencil condensor form-factor such as a shotgun mic or hyper-cardioid for dialogue. The most effective result for stereo recording inside a blimp will be to use M/S recording with a single mono mic and a single figure-8 microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Large Diaphragm Condenser mics (LDC) are typically not used for outdoor recording because they are too sensitive to damage from wind. Also, they are too large and heavy for practical hand-held use.  However, there have been DIY projects to make bilmp and furry covers for enclosures large enough for a pair of LDC. But typically mounted on a fixed stand rather than hand-held.

There are specialty forums for nature recording. A few years ago I saw a DIY project on one of them which showed a blimp large enough for a pair of LDC with a furry cover for wind protection.  Not clear whether it was successful enough to warrant the effort.  The fact that it is hard to find this combination would seem to indicate that not many people find it practical.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES and I did it.  I had to make my own blimp but it works quite nicely. The blimp is made of soft plastic garden fence (purchased from a local garden supply 24" wide 12 feet 1/2" sq openings in a roll).  Chopped off a 3+ foot piece and made a "log" 12" dia x 24" long tie it round with wire or small cable ties {overlap the edges a couple of inches}.  Your own your own to make a mounting bar- mine is a piece of 1" x 1/4" alum I had laying around.
The wind cover is 2 layers of tubular knit tee shirt fabric tied at each end.  Good luck